# Angular2 testing - method of an injected service is not defined

Tags: angular

I'm trying to test a component (`GamePanelComponent`) which uses a service:
inside `GamePanelComponent.ts` :

```
constructor(private playerService: PlayersService, private leaderBoardService: LeaderBoardService) { }
```

`comp.IsValidMove` is uses the players service `getPlayers` method but unfortunately i'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPlayers' of undefined`

Here is my test file which was written according to Angular2 testing tutorial. As you can, see I DO inject a stub which has `getPlayers()` method (because it's an instance of the original service):

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';

import { GamePanelComponent } from './gamepanel.component';
import { GamePanelOutputComponent } from '../gamepaneloutput/gamepaneloutput.component';

import { PlayersService } from '../../services/players/players.service';
import { LeaderBoardService } from '../../services/leaderboard/leaderboard.service';

import { Player } from '../../models/player/player';

describe('GamePanelComponent (inline template)', () => {

  let comp:    GamePanelComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<GamePanelComponent>;  
  let playersService, playersServiceStub, componentPlayersService : PlayersService;

  beforeEach( async ( () => {

    this.playersServiceStub = new PlayersService();
    this.playersServiceStub.players = [];
    this.playersServiceStub.players[0] = new Player('','X');
    this.playersServiceStub.players[1] = new Player('','O');

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ GamePanelComponent, GamePanelOutputComponent ], // declare the test component
      providers:    [ { provide: PlayersService, useValue: playersServiceStub }, { provide: LeaderBoardService } ]
    }).compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GamePanelComponent);            
            comp = fixture.componentInstance;

            // PlayerService actually injected into the component
            playersService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(PlayersService);
            componentPlayersService = playersService;
            // PlayersService from the root injector
            playersService = TestBed.get(PlayersService);
        });
  }));

  it('isValidMove', () => {
      comp.ngOnInit();
      comp.game.board[0][0] = 'X';      
      let isValid = comp.isValidMove(0,0);
      expect(isValid).toBe(false);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supposed to use `this` in the `beforeEach` callback. It's not a class. Therefore `this.playersServiceStub` is not pointing to the same `playerServiceStub` declared outside the `beforeEach`. So you're passing undefined as the provider. Just use

```
playersServiceStub = new PlayersService();
```